# Как сериализовать arraycollection в symfony?

Tags: php, symfony2, сериализация, doctrine

Использую для сериализации **JMS** сериализатор, сериализую в `Json`.
Когда в сериализатор передаётся объект заполненный **ArrayCollection**(свойство **$peoples**), то на выходе мы получаем пустой **json-массив 'peoples:{}'**.

Но если передавать в сериализатор просто массив **array**(для получения массива в **peoples** сетится `$peoples->getValues()`) c объектами, то на выходе получаем заполненный **json-массив**, только в таком случае всё работает, перед сериализацией превращать объект в массив и потом при десериализации обратно в объект, появляется костыль. Свойство **peoples** обязательно должно быть объектом, т.к. мы в дальнейшем нуждаемся в использовании методов объекта.

**UPD к ссылке из коммента:**

В сущности настроен тип сериализации `@JMS\Type("ArrayCollection<AppBundle\Entity\Peoples>")`

И добавлен `@JMS\Expose()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45344427/jms-serializer-deserialize-arraycollection-of-objects